# C++ how to display text in child window at real time

Tags: c++, winapi

[image]

This application creates a child window (which is the white box) when I right click anywhere, and destroys the child window after another right click. I have implemented the mechanics to expand and shrink the red rectangle through Direct 2D. I would like the child window to display the width and height of the rectangle at real time, as I make changes to it. I do not interact with the child window at all: it doesn't need an "x" button for closing and stuff; it just prints out a couple lines of data.

Here is what I have in my main window procedure:

```
case WM_RBUTTONUP:
            {
                DemoApp *pDemoApp = reinterpret_cast<DemoApp *>(static_cast<LONG_PTR>(
                    ::GetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA)));
                pDemoApp->showTextBox = !pDemoApp->showTextBox;  //showTextBox is a boolean
                if (pDemoApp->showTextBox) {
                    POINTS cursor = MAKEPOINTS(lParam);
                    pDemoApp->child_hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
                        WS_EX_TOPMOST,
                        "LISTBOX",
                        "I dont need a title here",
                        WS_CHILDWINDOW,
                        cursor.x,
                        cursor.y,
                        100,
                        200,
                        pDemoApp->main_hwnd,
                        NULL,
                        HINST_THISCOMPONENT,
                        pDemoApp
                    );
                    ShowWindow(pDemoApp->child_hwnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
                    UpdateWindow(pDemoApp->child_hwnd);
                }
                else {
                    DestroyWindow(pDemoApp->child_hwnd);
                }
            }
            break;
```

How may I go from here? I would like to know:

1. Is using Direct Write to draw text in the child window my only option? I see the dashed lines in the white box so I assume there must be a way to display plain text.
2. I used `LISTBOX` here, which is a predefined windows class name. How do I set a procedure for it? What else predefined class name can better suit my need? Or do I have to register a custom one;
3. I would like to drag the child window around, how can I set it up so that the system handles dragging for me.
4. Would popping a dialog box to display text be better than popping a child window?

Thanks.

Comment: 1: In `WM_PAINT`, use `TextOut(hdc, 0, 0, L"test", 4);` or other GDI functions for drawing. 2: ListBox usually doesn't need its own procedure, but you can use `SetWindowSubclass` to override some of its functionality (you should leave that for later). 3: Use `RegisterClass` to make another child class with a different name and procedure, create a child window with that class name. 4: Yes. Please focus your question on one thing.

Comment: Appreciate your help! I made it work with Dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using a Win32 [`LISTBOX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/list-boxes) control as the child window, then you have a couple of options for displaying the rectangle's dimensions in it:

- give the ListBox the `LBS_HASSTRINGS` style, and add 1-2 items to it. Then, any time you change the rectangle, send `LB_DELETESTRING` and `LB_ADDSTRING` messages to the ListBox's `HWND` to display the updated dimensions as needed.  A ListBox does not have a way to *update* an existing item, so to change an existing item's text, you have to remove the item and then re-add it with the new text.
- give the ListBox an `LBS_OWNERDRAW...` style, and add 1-2 blank item(s) in it.  Then have the ListBox's *parent window* handle `WM_MEASUREITEM` and `WM_DRAWITEM` notifications from the ListBox to display the rectangle's current dimensions in the item(s) as needed.  Whenever the rectangle is changed, call `InvalidateRect()` on the ListBox's `HWND` to trigger a redraw.

Comment: Thanks! I made it work using Dialog. LISTBOX isnt what I want. But thanks anyway!